# Run Pyspark job using Matillion

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, etl, data-warehouse, matillion

I have a setup where i need to run PySpark jobs using Matillion tool. I know we can run pure python jobs on Matillion but in my case we also require Spark, Hadoop and other softwares to run the job.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.